# SharePoint - Machine Translation Service, PowerPoint Automation Service and Word Automation Service

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, service, word-automation, machine-translation

Do these services:

- Machine Translation Service
- PowerPoint Automation Service
- Word Automation Service

  need an office online server for their functionality?

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need to have SharePoint installed. it is no need  to have OOS to use them.

About these services:

[Machine Translation Services in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/machine-translation-services-in-sharepoint)

[PowerPoint Automation Services in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/powerpoint-automation-services-in-sharepoint)

[Word Automation Services Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee558830(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: if you want to open word/ppt in browser, yes, you need to install OOS. It is a situation that you need to open the word/ppt file then save as pdf. However, there is another situation that you can use code to transfer the file without opening it. So, OOS is not necessary for these services, just optional.

Answer (score 1):

Office Online Server is an Office server product that provides browser-based file viewing and editing services for Office files.

Other services that you have mentioned in the question do not have any dependency for Office Online server.

Please follow the link below to get a view of the pre-requisites needed before configuring Office online server.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/plan-office-online-server

Let me know in case of any further questions.

Comment: How does PowerPoint Automation Service and Word Automation Service then work, because I thought that if I open word / ppt in my browser, I can save it as a pdf. Another way to solve it did not occur to me. 

When I want to use Machine Translation Service, I can translate documents either in a browser or using SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow using Action Translate. After the request is processed, it sends the request to the Microsoft Translator cloud host service where the actual translation work is performed. 

Based on these things, I assumed it was necessary to have OOS installed.

Comment: if you want to open word/ppt in browser,  yes, you need to install OOS. It is a situation that you need to open the word/ppt file then save as pdf. However, there is another situation that you can use code to transfer the file without opening it. So, OOS is not necessary for these services, just optional.